# Multi-step / nested scrapy file download

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to download file using a custom scrapy pipeline. However the file url is not trivial to obtain. Here is the steps :

- pipeline get an item containing a `pdfLink` attribute
- the page at `pdfLink` is a wrapper of the pdf, which is embedded in an iframe

I then extend the FilesPipeline class :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline

class PdfPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, spider):
        yield scrapy.Request(item['pdfLink'],
            callback=self.get_pdfurl)



    def get_pdfurl(self, response):
        import logging
        logging.info('...............')
        print response.url
        yield scrapy.Request(response.css('iframe::attr(src)').extract()[0])
```

However :

1. files that are downloaded are the web pages pointed out by `pdfLink` and not the embedded pdf file.
2. neither the `print` or `logging.info` are shown in logs.

It then seems that the get_pdfurl is not called back. Am I doing something wrong ? How is it possible to download such a nested file ?

Comment: Have you used a debugger to see what item['pdfLink'] returns, or even if it returns anything at all?

Comment: it does return the right url of the pdf wrapper. This url is then downloaded as my pdf file. This is the same behavior as I do not set the callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by using two consecutive pipelines, where the first is build like in [Item pipeline - Take screenshot of item](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#take-screenshot-of-item).

```
class PdfWrapperPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        wrapper_url = self.WRAPPER_URL.format(item.get('pdfLink'))
        request = scrapy.Request(item.get('pdfLink'))
        dfd = spider.crawler.engine.download(request, spider)
        dfd.addBoth(self.return_item, item)
        return dfd

    def return_item(self, response, item):
        if response.status != 200:
            # Error happened, return item.
            return item

        url = response.css('iframe::attr(src)').extract()[0]
        item['pdfUrl'] = url
        return item

class PdfPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, spider):
        yield scrapy.Request(item.get('pdfUrl'))
```

and then set in `settings.py` the wrapper pipeline priority higher than the pdf pipeline priority.

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'project.pipelines.PdfWrapperPipeline': 1,
    'project.pipelines.PdfPipeline': 2,
}
```

Response has been first posted in the [scrapy's github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3185)